# Python 3 and unicode string equality

Tags: python, unicode

According to the Unicode specification these two strings are supposed to be equal because of unicode equivalence ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Errors_due_to_normalization_differences )

```
s1 = "\u006E\u0303"
s2 = "\u00F1"
```

But `s1 == s1` returns `False`. I can't find on the Python webSite anything that states what `==` means for unicode string in Python?

For instance, this definition is clear for Swift ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html ). I can't see anything similar for Python.

Comment: `==` for Unicode strings compares the codepoints (*scalars* in Swift) in the strings, nothing else. There is no support for extended grapheme clusters (*characters*) like Swift has.

Comment: Equivalence and equality are different things.

Comment: Martijn: Is there anything in the documentation that states that?
Stefan: I agree that equality is ill-defined unicode strings, but the wikipedia page states that "Therefore, those sequences should be displayed in the same manner, should be treated in the same way by applications such as alphabetizing names or searching, and may be substituted for each other".

Comment: This might explain it a bit, at least it says "... they may not compare equal". https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize

Comment: Stefan: thanks. I am just very puzzled now to what regular expression do. I still believe that the Python documentation is very fuzzy here. Thanks for your help and comments.